# Possible to pass name as argument to c++ template?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to write a class:

```
template<typename T, ... name> struct Magic {
  T name;
};
```

such that:

```
Magic<int, foo> gives:

Magic<int, foo> {
  int foo;
}
```

and

```
Magic<float, bar> gives:

Magic<float, bar> {
  float bar;
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to specify not only the Type, but also the name of the member variables.

Comment: Templates handle types. The only names they can refer to are type names, not lexical names. Preprocessor is for lexical names.

Comment: the only way I can think of is using inheritance+ crtp pattern, like `struct bar_variable{ float bar; }; struct Magic<named_variable> : named_variable {}; Magic<bar_variable>;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not possible, you have to resort to either macro-based solutions or use a predefined set of types that provide named members.

A possible macro-based approach:

```
#define MAGIC(name_) \
    template<typename T> struct Magic1 { \
        T name_; \
    };

MAGIC(foo);
```

or:

```
#define MAGIC(type_, name_) \
    struct Magic1 { \
        type_ name_; \
    };

MAGIC(foo);
```

Using preprocessor magic, e.g. utilizing [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), you should be able to generate *n* named members in a more convenient way.

Another approach might be using a predefined set of classes providing certain named members from that you inherit:

```
enum { MemberNameFoo, MemberNameBar };

template<class T, int id>
struct named_member;

template<class T>
struct named_member<T, MemberNameFoo> {
    T foo;
};

template<class T>
struct named_member<T, MemberNameBar> {
    T bar;
};

// holder for the above, just one member for this example:

template<class T, int name>
struct holder : named_member<T, name> {};

// using it:

typedef holder<int, MemberNameFoo> HasFoo;
typedef holder<int, MemberNameBar> HasBar;
```

Using compile-time lists you could then inherit from *n* `named_member` instantiations, [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) could help here.

Comment: If you don't actually care too much what your members are named exactly, you can do this with typelists or in C++0x variadic templates.  I've done it to implement classes that wrote their own serialization and deserialization methods.

Comment: But the question is about wether its *"possible to pass name[s]"* to a template, not how to generate a holder for some arbitrarily named collection of types.

Comment: @gf, this is true.  Though often people don't ask the question they exactly mean.  They have a solution in mind for a problem and ask how to make the solution work, not how to solve the actual problem.  :-)

Comment: Right, but unless i can guess what exact problem underlies the question it is all highly speculative until clarified.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.  There is a construct called a [typelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901907/how-to-use-typelists) that can be used to sort of achieve an effect like you're after.  Unfortunately, even then you won't get named members, you will get accessor functions with names like `MyClass::getField<1>()`.

In C++0x you can do better than typelists with [variadic templates](http://www.generic-programming.org/~dgregor/cpp/variadic-templates.html).  But you will still have accessor functions that look just like the C++ case.

It's tempting to put down a variadic template example here because it wouldn't be too huge.  Unfortunately I think that doing it well would require a few hours of research on my part to learn exactly how variadic templates worked.  I could do a stupid version relatively easily, but I expect the stupid version would be a lot less nice in various ways than a well done version.