# Array of templated structs

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I have structs templated by int derived from a Base struct.

```c++
struct Base { int i; double d; }; 
template< int N > struct Derv : base { static const int mN = N; };
```

I need to make an array of Derv< N > where N can vary for each struct in that array. I know C/C++ does not allow arrays of objects of different types, but is there a way around this? I was thinking of separating the type information somehow (hints like pointers to Base struct or usage of union spring to my mind, but with all of these I don't know how to store the type information of each array element for usage DURING COMPILE TIME). As you can see, the memory pattern of each Derv< N > is the same.

I need to access the type of each array element for template specialization later in my code. The general aim of this all is to have a compile-time dispatch mechanism without the need to do a runtime "type switch" somewhere in the code.

Comment: At the moment I don't see anything useful in having `Derv` be a templated class. None at all. So first you should be wondering if you are asking the right question.

Comment: Make vector of vectors of `Base`, and done.

Comment: The point of that is the argument for static dispatch (I did not want to include the whole code, but in general there are templated functions which behave differently per the type of Derv). All that happen in performance crucial code, so virtuals, function pointers and similar such things I would rather avoid.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: yes, but how do I keep the type info per element?

Comment: @JakubMertlik: Via the `size()` member function.

Comment: @KerrekSB: ok, maybe I am misunderstanding you, but wouldn't that be a bit wastefull to allocate 10 Base for N=10?

Comment: Consider using a typelist instead of an array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901907/how-to-use-typelists

Comment: @JakubMertlik: No, sorry, it was I who misunderstood. I thought the `N` would be part of the array size. Never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most certainly impossible. If you did

```
int i;
std::cin >> i;
some_magic_array X[size];
```

Then what is the type of `X[i]`? Oh, wait, you can't possibly know. It's nothing C++ specific, it's *fundamentally impossible*. That's why no `some_magic_array` will ever exist that permits this.

Unless you effectively use a `std::tuple` and guarantee that `i` is constexpr. Then you absolutely can do this with `std::get<i>(tup);`.

Comment: OK, I will analyze that and the Alexandrescu's typelist to see if that helps. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use `ptr = dynamic_cast<Type>(element);` .. `ptr` will equal to `NULL` if it's the wrong type.
For example:

```
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

struct Base { int i; double d; Base(){}; virtual ~Base(){};}; 
template< int N > struct Derv : public Base { static const int mN = N; ~Derv(){}; };

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Base* arr[2];
    arr[0] = new Derv<10>;
    arr[1] = new Derv<5>;
    Derv<10> *ptr = dynamic_cast<Derv<10>* >(arr[0]);
    Derv<5> *ptr2 = dynamic_cast<Derv<5>* >(arr[0]);
    cout << ptr << endl << ptr2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
// That should print 
0x9571008 //ptr to object will differ every time.
0 // Null because of wrong type.
```

But you'll need to define virtual destructor in your struct for this to work, and/or a virtual function.

Comment: isn't dynamic_cast<> working for structs with virtuals only? Also, I would need to check the return value at runtime, which is equivalent to a type switch (which I want to avoid).

Comment: Yes, needs virtuals .. Aha .. Well, what's in your mind to avoid Type Switiching, as you don't know the type of the element of the array?!

Comment: static dispatch via template specialization (described in one of the comments above).

Comment: You can make templated functions, and let the compiler do the linkage. :D as in 
`void operate(Derv<10> obj) {}` ... etc.

Comment: Yes, but how to make the array of Derv< N >? (that was the original question).