# Simulation of variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm writing a small wrapper for our API and I have encountered a problem.
Each call from external client(JavaScript engine) is made be calling function from ApiBase named execute, all parameters are passed as std::string, no mather what was passed in api call, every value is converted to string.

My idea is to use pointer-to-member-function and try to convert those passed string into C++ types that programmer who is writing specific function need to have.

For example:

```
struct MyApiForVeryImportantDevice{
void Init(int, int);
};

MyApiForVeryImportantDevice api_entry;
ApiBase* api = make_api(&api_entry, &MyApiForVeryImportantDevice::Init);

//serve api
```

Somwhere in code `api->execute("1", "2", "", "")` gets called with 4 o 10 string parameters(always 4 or  10), no mather how many parameters where passed in api call(don't ask me why...).

I know this can be done with variadic templates but unfortunetly I can't use it in this project. 
My solution is based on "simulating variadic templates" but it just ugly. To support to 10 parameters I need to write 10 classes ApiCall and 10 make_api functions and this is error prone, do you have any other idea? Some kind of mpl(maybe type lists?)?
Code presented below is just example for 2 and 10 parameters and I need something like this for 0-10 parameters.

Regards.

```
template<class T>
T convert(const string& v){
    return T();
}

template<>
int convert(const string& v)
{
    return boost::lexical_cast<int>(v);
}


template<class T, class R, class A0, class A1, class A2, class A3, class A4, class A5, class A6, class A7, class A8, class A9>
class ApiCall : public ApiBase
{
    typedef T result_type;
    typedef R class_type;
    typedef boost::function<result_type(class_type*,A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)> functor_type;

    ApiCall(T* obj, functor_type f)
    {
        func = boost::bind(f, _1, obj);
    }

    virtual void execute(const string& param1, const string& param2, const string& param3, const string& param4)
    {   
        func(convert<A0>(param0), convert<A1>(param1), convert<A2>(param2), convert<A3>(param3), convert<A4>(param4));
    }

    virtual void execute(const string& param0, const string& param1, const string& param2, const string& param3,
                         const string& param4, const string& param5, const string& param6, const string& param7
                         const string& param8, const string& param9)
    {       
        func(convert<A0>(param0), convert<A1>(param1), convert<A2>(param2), convert<A3>(param3), convert<A4>(param4), convert<A5>(param5), 
                     convert<A6>(param6),convert<A7>(param7), convert<A8>(param8), convert<A9>(param9));
    }

private:
    functor_type func;
};

template<class T, class R, class A0, class A1>
class ApiCall : public ApiBase
{
    typedef R result_type;
    typedef T class_type;
    typedef boost::function<result_type(class_type*,A0, A1)> functor_type;

    ApiCall(T* obj, functor_type f)
    {
        func = boost::bind(f, _1, obj);
    }

    virtual void execute(const string& param1, const string& param2, const string& param3, const string& param4)
    {   
        func(convert<A0>(param0), convert<A1>(param1));
    }

    virtual void execute(const string& param0, const string& param1, const string& param2, const string& param3,
                         const string& param4, const string& param5, const string& param6, const string& param7
                         const string& param8, const string& param9)
    {       
        func(convert<A0>(param0), convert<A1>(param1));
    }

private:
    functor_type func;
};

template<class T, class R, class A0, class A1>
ApiCall<T, R, A0, A1>* make_api(T obj, R(T::*fun)(A0, A1))
{
    return new ApiCall<T,R,A0,A!>(obj, fun);
}

template<class T, class R, class A0, class A1, class A2, class A3, class A4, class A5, class A6, class A7, class A8, class A9>
ApiCall<T,R,A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8, A9>* make_api(T obj, R(T::*fun)(A0))
{
    return new ApiCall<T,R,A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>(obj, fun);
}
```

Comment: Do you know typelists? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901907/how-to-use-typelists

Answer (score 1):

I think that ***typelists*** can be used here to simulate variadic templates.

Typelists are a template metaprogramming construct that acts as a likned-list of types. Were introduced by Andrei Alexandrescu in his book [*"Modern C++ design"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C++_Design).
Basically a typelist is a class like this:

```
template<typename HEAD , typename TAIL>
struct type_list
{
    typedef HEAD head;
    typedef TAIL tail;
};
```

And can be used as bellow:

```
//A typelist wich stores int, bool, and char:
typedef type_list<int,type_list<bool,type_list<char, nil>>> list;
```

`nil` is a type used as sentinel to mark the end of the list. 
We can use C macros to define shortcuts to make typelist definitions easy:

```
#define MAKE_TYPELIST_1( type_1 ) type_list<type_1,nil>
#define MAKE_TYPELIST_2( type_1 , type_2 ) type_list<type_1,MAKE_TYPELIST_1( type_2 )>
#define MAKE_TYPELIST_3( type_1 , type_2 , type_3 ) type_list<type_1,MAKE_TYPELIST_2( type_2 , type_3 )>
```

... and so on.

You can use this construct to pass the types of the parameters without variadic templates:

```
template<typename T , typename R , typename ARGS_LIST>
class APICall ...

typedef APICall<...,MAKE_TYPELIST_3(std::string,std::string,std::string)> tree_strings_call;
```

I suggest you to checkout the chapter three of Modern C++ design. There are a full explanation of typelists, its operations (index_of, type_at, etc), and good examples of its use.

Comment: I'm trying to use typelist to get his work, but how ca I store a functor(pointer-to-member-funtcion) with arbitrary number of parameters fo further call?