# How to construct C++ variadic function with regular function parameters alongside

Tags: c++

```
template<class... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args) << "\n";
}
  
void test(){

    print(1, ':', " Hello", 2 ,  ',', " ", "World!");
}
```

Above works for text

```
template<class... Args>
void add(int & i, Args... args)
{
    i += args...;
}



void test(){

    int i;
    add(i, 1, 2, 3);
    
}
```

Edit:
This does not compile as its fake code but is similar function possible for filling vector with data of data types?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: *"looks like your post is mostly code"* Don't try to game the system. Improve your post instead, e.g. add the exact error messages.

Comment: Sorry, its fake code. Im wondering if similar code is possible.

Comment: `i = (args + ...);`.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. `(i += ... += args);` or `args += (args + ...);`, but you need to zero-initialize the `i` (or use what Marek R suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of going over the args (in this case all of the same type),
if this is not enough for you consider looking into type lists.
[How to use typelists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901907/how-to-use-typelists)

```
// With recursion and if constexpr
template<typename arg_t, typename... args_t>
constexpr auto sum_recurse(arg_t n, args_t&&... ns)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args_t) == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return n + sum_recurse(ns...);
    }
}

// or in this case for operations you can use fold expressions
template<typename... args_t>
constexpr auto sum_fold(args_t&&... args)
{
    return (args + ...);
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(sum_recurse(1, 2, 3) == 6);
    static_assert(sum_fold(1, 2, 3) == 6);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lambda to iterate input parameters.

```
void add(int & i, Args... args)
{

    ([&] (auto & param)
       {

        i += param;

       } (args), ...);

}



void main(){

    int i=0;
    add(i, 1, 2, 3);
    assert(i == 3);
    
    cout<<"ok";
}
```

Overkill for addition, but for many purposes useful if newer C++ standard supported.